# Nil inherited outlet

Tags: xcode, swift, inheritance

I've defined a base class which has an UITableView outlet.

```
class BaseController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
...
```

Then I've inherited the class as follows:

```
class SubViewController: BaseController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
   tableView.rowHeight = screenHeigth / CGFloat(textArray.count)
```

But the tableView is nil, I've just recently started programming in swift, is it possible to inherit an outlet? If so, how should I do it?

I'm currently using Xcode 6.4

Comment: On the subclass, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inherit an outlet. In your storyboard (assumption), the view controller class name should be set to the name of your *subclass*. You can then connect up the table view to the outlet in the storyboard.

Comment: So, must you declare a view controller in your storyboard for each view you want to show in your app? Can't you declare a "layout" view controller and create multiple view controllers from it?

Comment: No, because the storyboard instantiates an instance of the view controller class specified in the Storyboard, so you would end up with an instance of the superclass.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know.